# JavaScript: Collection is null in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, null

I'm writing a JavaScript/JQuery method to refactor the input value of an inserted number in an input box. The nonFractions collection are the numbers before the decimal separator. However, when I run this script, I get the issue that  in the following line:

```
for(var i=0 ; i < nonFractions.length ; i++) {
```

My variable nonFractions equal is to `null`. How does this come? I don't see the issue.

My total code:

```
$("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").change(function(){
    var amount = $("#queryInstructedAmountFrom").val();
    amount = removeZeros(amount);
    var splittedValues = amount.split(/[,.]/);
    amount = "";

    if(splittedValues.length == 1) {
        amount += splittedValues[0];
        var nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
        var firstIndex = amount.length % 3;
        if(firstIndex != 0) {
        var firstNumbers = amount.substr(0, firstIndex);
        amount = amount.substr(firstIndex);
        nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);

        amount = "";

        amount += firstNumbers;
        amount += thousandSeparator;
        } else {
            amount = "";
        }
        for(var i=0 ; i < nonFractions.length ; i++) {
            amount += nonFractions[i];

            if(i < (nonFractions.length - 1)){
                amount += thousandSeparator;
            }
        }

        amount += decimalSeparator;
        amount += "00";
    } else {
        for(var i=0 ; i < splittedValues.length - 1 ; i++) {
            amount += splittedValues[i];
        }

        nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
        var firstIndex = amount.length % 3;
        alert(firstIndex);
        if(firstIndex == 0) {
            nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
        }

        if(firstIndex > 1) {
            var firstNumbers = amount.substr(0, firstIndex);
            amount = amount.substr(firstIndex);
            nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);

            amount = "";
            amount += firstNumbers;
            amount += thousandSeparator;
        } else {

            alert(nonFractions);
            amount = "";
        }
        for(var i=0 ; i < nonFractions.length ; i++) {
            amount += nonFractions[i];

            if(i < (nonFractions.length - 1)){
                amount += thousandSeparator;
            }
        }

        amount += decimalSeparator;
        amount += splittedValues[splittedValues.length -1];
    }
```

Can someone give me the solution?

Comment: Wouldn't you encounter an issue because your variable declaration is within your beginning if statement?  What would happen if splittedValues.length != 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
```

If `amount.match` does not find the regex you're looking for, it returns `null`. [See MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

You can get around this by adding a condition:

```
if (nonFractions == null) {
    nonFractions = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
if(firstIndex != 0) {
  var firstNumbers = amount.substr(0, firstIndex);
  amount = amount.substr(firstIndex);
  nonFractions = amount.match(/.{1,3}/g);
...
```

If your input was originally the value '1', at this point, firstNumbers becomes '1', then amount is substringed and becomes '', then you try to match characters again, but since amount is empty string, there is no match and nonFractions becomes null.

what exactly is your goal?  I would suggest you create an input/output table to better get an idea of what your algorithm needs to be.